# How to retrieve an R-output saved in a txt file

Tags: r, import, output

Here is my problem. Suppose you fitted a simple regression model in R.

```
n <- 100
x <- runif(n)
y <- rnorm(n)
TheModel <- lm(y ~ x)
```

Suppose you saved the estimated coefficients and the residuals as a two-elements list in a txt file with the command capture.output in a specific location in your computer (e.g., the desktop).

**Problem:** How can you retrieve that two-elements list when using another R-session? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What do you want to extract?  WIth `capture.output`, you are storing as a string.  If you want to save the model, use `save` or `save.image`  or `saveRDS`

Comment: Thanks for your interest, @akrun. I would like to extract the residuals from the exported list when using another R-session.

Comment: I would suggest you to save the object instead of `capture.output`

Comment: Your suggestion worked, @akrun! :)